# Preventing a UIWebView from scrolling after tapping a link

Tags: uiwebview, uiscrollview

I've got a `UIWebView` which is displaying a long chunk of HTML with multiple embedded images that are wrapped in links.  The webview is scrollable so that content "below the fold" is accessible.

When the links are tapped, I'm using the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:navigationType` method to catch a specific JavaScript call, which then triggers a modal load of a UIViewController over the top of the webview.

As soon as the link is tapped, the webview's `contentOffset` is reset to `0,0`, so the page appears to "jump" back to the top. Ideally, I'd like the webView's `contentOffset` to remain where it is until the modal view controller is dismissed.

I've tried setting the `webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled` property to `NO` as soon as the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method is called - this doesn't stop the webView scrolling.

I've also tried saving the `contentOffset` value at the point where the link is tapped, and then manually resetting it - but again, this doesn't stop the webView from scrolling.

Is there any way of preventing this scrolling from happening??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be nothing to do with `UIWebView` at all, and is standard browser behaviour.

The links in the HTML were in the form

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('js-call:image-xx');">
  <img src='foo.jpg'>
</a>
```

The problem was that I hadn't defined the `#` anchor, so the page was scrolling back to the top when the   So altering the HTML to

```
<a name="image-xx">
<a href="image-xx" onClick="window.open('js-call:image-xx');">
  <img src='foo.jpg'>
</a>
```

fixes the issue.